# Создание сайта по навигации по городу

Tags: любой-язык

Я не программист и мне интересно как можно создать вот это (интересно именно какой язык выбрать) : 
я понимаю как сделать карту города с отметками (в иллюстраторе). А как сделать так, чтобы к этим отметкам были привязаны определенные здания (допустим, кафе, обычной вставкой ссылки?) И чтобы и мероприятия которые там проводятся были привязаны к данной точки кафе. Обновление новостей и различных событий которые проводятся в данном кафе были автоматически.
Т.е. есть карта города, что то типа этого ( http://onbike.by/Minsk/) на карте помечены метки расположения кафе, а когда наводишь на метку(или кликаешь) показываться не только статичный текст (график работы, Адрес) но и мероприятия, которые на сегодняшний день там проводятся? Ещё хочется сделать стандартный поиск (по названию, адресу) и поиск по мероприятиям (нажимаешь на поиск и вводишь экология и смотришь какие и где мероприятия проводятся).

Answer (score 0):

Всё делается с помощью готовых библиотек. С нуля вы вряд ли будете такое писать. Так что можно использовать почти любой популярный язык. Достаточно, чтобы в нём были нужные библиотеки.

Чтобы добавить мероприятия, нужно откуда-то получить информацию о них, то есть нужны библиотеки для работы с базами данных или API для извлечения информации с нужных сайтов.

Для поиска нужен текстовый обработчик - ещё одна библиотека и т.д..

Если хотите именно изучить, как все эти библиотеки работают, то нужно читать множество статей, мануалов и т.д.. Среднестатический программист редко придумывают алгоритмы сам, обычно соединяют работу разных готовых библиотек, написанных другими программистами.